# How to find words in a 2D array of characters and return the unused characters in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Imagine the following 2D array:

```
[
["a","b","c"]
["d","e","f"]
["g","h","i"]
]
```

a give word is :"iea"
the expected output is string :
"bcdfgh"

Comment: What have **YOU** tried / researched so far? Share **YOUR** code / thoughts / findings

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: What if the input is `"aec"` ?

Comment: @MrSmith42 so I know how to iterate in the array vertically, horizontally and diagonally but the question is how to update the array accordingly?

Comment: @clamp  so the function gets and input of an array and a string"aec" and should return a string

Comment: @Paarmin why is the characters array 2D? Is this a requirement? If so, why?

Comment: @AlexH Yes is is the requirement!

Comment: @Paarmin Why is this a requirement? This looks like it might be an example of the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function, like this:

```js
let arr = [
    ["a","b","c"],
    ["d","e","f"],
    ["g","h","i"]
];

function sumOfFilter(arr,word) {
    return arr // Return the character list,
      .flat(1) // converted into a 1D array,
      .filter(e => !word.includes(e)) // filtered to elements not in the word,
      .join(''); // joined together in a string.
}

console.log(sumOfFilter(arr,"iea"))
```

Comment: Very concise solution!

Comment: Hey @Paarmin: if this answer (or any answer) answered your question, you can [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). This indicates to the community that it worked for you and solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're storing the characters in a 2D array. You'll need them in a 1D array to easily work with them for this question.

```js
let word = "iea";

let characters = [
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  ["d", "e", "f"],
  ["g", "h", "i"]
];

// By default, all characters are unused
let unused = characters.flat(1);

// For each row of the 2d array
for (let characterRow = 0; characterRow < characters.length; characterRow++) {
  // For each column of the 2d array
  for (let column = 0; column < characters[characterRow].length; column++) {
    // Find the entry in the 2d array
    let charToTest = characters[characterRow][column];

    // If it is used in the word
    if (word.includes(charToTest)) {
      // Remove from unused array
      let usedCharacterIndex = unused.indexOf(charToTest);
      unused.splice(usedCharacterIndex, 1);
    }
  }
}

console.log(unused);
console.log(unused.join("")); // Joined together as a string
```

This iterates through each character in the 2D array. If it is used in the word, it removes it from the list of unused characters.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = [
    ["a","b","c"],
    ["d","e","f"],
    ["g","h","i"]
];
console.log(arr.flat(1).filter(e=>/[^iea]/.test(e)).join(''))
```